# Convert a df to dictionary based on some condition

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a dataframe, I want to have the data for each id in one row. Some of the columns are constant for each id and
some of them are changing. For example, val1 and val2 is constant in the following example.

So, I want to build a dictionary from this dataframe.
Key is the id and the value is a list which is [number of row for each id, its t, val1, val2].
Here is an example, for id=1 we have 2 t, its value is 1, 2, so '1': [2, 1, 2, 1, 5] is the first key and value. For id=2
we have the same thins. Could you please help me with that? Thanks

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['id'] = [1, 1, 2, 2, 2,2]
df['t'] = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5,6]
df['val1'] = [1,1,0,0,0,0 ]
df['val2'] = [5,5, 4, 4,4,4]
out:
dic = {'1': [2, 1, 2, 1, 5], '2': [4, 3, 4, 5,6, 0,4]}
```

Comment: So, will `val1` and `val2` be the same for every `id`?  So, does [2,1,2,1,5] mean "there were 2 rows with this ID, the `t` values were 1 and 2, and the common val1 was 1 and the common val2 was 5"?

Comment: yes. val 1 and val 2 is same for every id. yes exactly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df.groupby('id').agg({'t':list, 'val1':'first', 'val2':'first'}).apply(lambda x: [len(x.t),*x.t,x.val1,x.val2], axis=1).to_dict()
```

Answer (score 2):

It's just brute force.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame()
df['id'] = [1, 1, 2, 2, 2,2]
df['t'] = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5,6]
df['val1'] = [1,1,0,0,0,0 ]
df['val2'] = [5,5, 4, 4,4,4]

print(df)

lastid = None
tval = []
rows = []
for i,row in df.iterrows():
    if row['id'] != lastid:
        if lastid:
            rows.append( [len(tval)] + tval + save )
        lastid = row['id']
        tval = []
    tval.append(row['t'])
    save = [row['val1'],row['val2']]
    
rows.append( [len(tval)] + tval + save )

print(rows)
```

Output:

```
   id  t  val1  val2
0   1  1     1     5
1   1  2     1     5
2   2  3     0     4
3   2  4     0     4
4   2  5     0     4
5   2  6     0     4
[[2, 1, 2, 1, 5], [4, 3, 4, 5, 6, 0, 4]]
```